# c++ log function is using floating point precision

Tags: c++, floating-point, logging, floating-accuracy

I am having an interesting seg fault in the following function when I give it a number very close to 1.0. Specifically when the number would be rounded to 1.0 at *FLOATING POINT* precision.

```
double get_random_element(double random_number)
{
    if (random_number <= 0.0 || random_number >= 1.0)
        throw std::runtime_error("Can't have a random number not on the range (0.0, 1.0)");
    return -log(-log(random_number));
}
```

If random_number is 1.0 then log(1.0) = 0.0 and the log of zero is an undefined calculation leading to a seg fault. However I would have thought that the error checking on the first line would have prevented this from ever happening. Ddebugging shows that a number very close to 1 will pass through the error checking but return 0 from the log function anyway leading me to believe that the log function is using only single floating point precision.

my includes are as follows so i can only assume I'm using the log from math.h

```
#include <string>
#include <math.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <map>
#include <boost/random/mersenne_twister.hpp>
#include <boost/random/uniform_int.hpp>
#include <boost/random/uniform_real.hpp>
#include <boost/random/variate_generator.hpp>
#include <utility>
```

UPDATE: As pointed out an easy solution is to just use a floating point number as the argument and if a number equal to 1.0f is passed in to just remove std::numeric_limits::epsilon() to give a number which can be safely passed into the double log.

But the question I'd like answered is why does calling double log of a number near but not equal to 1 fail.

UPDATE 2: After recreating this problem in a test project I think the problem is actually in the inputs. If I pass in

```
double val = 1.0 - std::numerical_limits<double>::epsilon();
```

I have no problems with the function. However what I actually pass in is

```
boost::mt19937 random_generator;
double val = (random_generator()+1)/4294967297.0;
```

where random_generator is designed to return a number on the range [0, 2^32 - 1] == [0,4294967295]. So I decided to punch in the largest possible return value

```
double val = (4294967295+1)/4294967297.0;
```

which quickly gave me a warning about unsigned int overflow and sure enough generated a zero. I am recompiling with the following:

```
get_random_element((random_generator()+1.0)/4294967297.0);
```

and hopefully this strange behaviour will be resolved.

UPDATE 3: I have finally found what is going on here... and as usual it comes down to user error (myself being the error). There was a second control path leading to this method which temporarily stored the double value as a float and then converted it back to double leading to 0.999999999 being rounded to 1.0 and then passed into the -log(-log(x)) function and causing it to fall over. What I still don't understand is why my checking

```
 if (random_number <= 0.0 || random_number >= 1.0) throw runtime_error(blah)
```

didn't catch the erroneous input before it was passed into the log functions?

Comment: No need to _assume_; use `::log` and preprocess your source to verify

Comment: are you sure it's a seg fault?

Comment: @sehe running a preprocessor shows math.h log functions imported @david not sure if it's a seg fault or just an unsupported opertation... but it kills the host application pretty good either way :)

Comment: @Jamie: Surely its the comparison between a `double` and `1.0f` which is the problem?

Comment: What compiler are you using ? Most importantly, what options did you pass about floating point operations (/fp:... with visual studio) ? Did you try with 1.0 instead of 1.0f (it shouldn't change anything) ? Did you try `r + std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon() > 1` instead of `r >= 1` ?

Comment: @quamrana: IIRC 1.0f will be converted to double first.

Comment: Also your function is *very sensitive* to what happens around 1. If you remove a few epsilons when you are close to 1, the result changes dramatically !

Comment: @quamrana - that is a nice catch but it's a a typo in the cut/paste to stackoverflow. @Alexandre the function is meant to be very sensitive :) It's part of the generation of a random value from an extreme value distribution

Comment: @Jamie: yep, this rang me a bell. By the way, the `<random>` header in C++0x provides you with extreme value deviates (and correct floating point semantics).

Comment: @alexandre floating point semantics: Precise (/fp:precise), RE <random> giving EV deviates: o rly? I will have to look that up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think quamrana has a good point (it immediately drew my attention too). However, I've been able to run this snippet for considerable length:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <boost/random/mersenne_twister.hpp>
#include <boost/random/uniform_real.hpp>

double get_random_element(double random_number)
{
    if (random_number <= 0 || random_number >= 1.0f)
        throw std::runtime_error("Can't have a random number not on the range (0.0, 1.0)");
    return -::log(-::log(random_number));
}

int main()
{
    boost::mt19937 rng; 
    boost::uniform_real<> random(std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon(),1);
    for (;;)
    {
        double r = random(rng);
        double gre = get_random_element(r);
        std::cout << "r = " << r << ", gre = " << gre << std::endl;
    }
    return 0; // not reached
}
```

E.g.:

```
sehe@meerkat:/tmp$ ./t | grep '^r = 0.999999' 
r = 0.999999, gre = 14.4777
r = 0.999999, gre = 13.7012
r = 0.999999, gre = 14.0492
r = 0.999999, gre = 14.1161
[.... many many lines snipped ....]
r = 0.999999, gre = 14.3691
r = 0.999999, gre = 13.424
r = 0.999999, gre = 14.4822
r = 0.999999, gre = 14.286
r = 0.999999, gre = 14.4344
r = 0.999999, gre = 14.0572
r = 0.999999, gre = 14.0607
r = 0.999999, gre = 14.1126
r = 0.999999, gre = 13.575
r = 0.999999, gre = 13.4754
r = 0.999999, gre = 13.5486
r = 0.999999, gre = 14.1983
^C

real    18m14.005s
user    20m5.667s
sys 12m19.302s
```

Perhaps you could use something similar in vein?

Comment: This makes me think that the problem may be with compiler flags. Try /fp:strict in MSVC (or the equivalent for your compiler) and see if the problem persists.

Comment: sehe, I've just updated the question... we are using a mersenne twister as you are but I'm not entirely sure what the uniform_real takes as arguments... are those inclusive or exclusive boundaries?

Comment: Simple documentation lookup: [`uniform_real models a random distribution. On each invocation, it returns a random floating-point value uniformly distributed in the range [min..max)`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/random/random-distributions.html#uniform_real). I'm surprised you would write the input distribution yourself, yet be paranoid enough to need to check that fact :)

Comment: paranoia is funny like that :P The problem I see with the above code is that it is guaranteed to fail if run for long enough because your rng should at some stage generate a 0 which would lead to log of zero and a fail. But maybe it would have made more sense for us to use boost::uniform_real<> random(std::numerical_limits<double>::epsilon(),1);

Comment: I'm updating the sample code so as not to confuse future visitors. (I must admit I totally missed the fact that 0 wasn't allowable too :))